# Counting row entries in BigQuery table grouped on a time interval using SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, time, group-by, google-bigquery

I've hit a bit of a dead end with this BigQuery/SQL question. After ~1 hour of Googling I still haven't figured it out, so I figured I'd ask here.

I have a BigQuery table (mycompany.engagement.product_orders) of customer order data. Every row in the table describes an order placed by a customer and it looks something like this:

| Row | Product | Timestamp | Type | CustomerName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 2021-08-19 11:41:08.874 UTC | Gala | Philippe Kahn |
| 2 | Orange | 2021-08-19 11:41:12.874 UTC | Navel | Grace Hopper |
| 3 | Pear | 2021-08-19 11:41:24.874 UTC | Bosc | Vladimir Nabokov |
| 4 | Apple | 2021-08-19 11:41:47.874 UTC | Melba | Sylvia Plath |
| 5 | Pear | 2021-08-19 11:41:55.874 UTC | Anjou | Alan Turing |
| 6 | Pear | 2021-08-19 11:42:10.874 UTC | Asian | Sylvia Plath |
| 7 | Apple | 2021-08-19 11:42:11.874 UTC | Fuji | Vladimir Nabokov |
| 8 | Orange | 2021-08-19 11:42:37.874 UTC | Blood | Ada Lovelace |
| 9 | Orange | 2021-08-19 11:42:49.874 UTC | Cara | Grace Hopper |
| 10 | Apple | 2021-08-19 11:42:51.874 UTC | Melba | Alan Turing |

I would like to formulate a SQL query that will count the products ordered by customers in 1 minute intervals (or any interval really) to return a table that looks (something) like this:

| Row | Product | Timestamp | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 2021-08-19 11:41:00.000 UTC | 2 |
| 2 | Orange | 2021-08-19 11:41:00.000 UTC | 1 |
| 3 | Pear | 2021-08-19 11:41:00.000 UTC | 2 |
| 4 | Pear | 2021-08-19 11:42:00.000 UTC | 1 |
| 5 | Apple | 2021-08-19 11:42:00.000 UTC | 2 |
| 6 | Orange | 2021-08-19 11:42:00.000 UTC | 2 |

Some notes:

The examples I found that were relevant (eg: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179823/grouping-count-by-interval-of-15-minutes) tend to provide counts for all row entries, not aggregated by a column value on the increment. I know this *might* be possible using partition by or group by statements but I'm not entirely sure or how I would structure them together. If it's not possible that'd be great to know - my SQL skills are still pretty nascent.

Attempt:
Following the framework of the link posted above which is somewhat similar to mine:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_ADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', timestamp) / 1)*1, '20000101'),
    count(*)
FROM 
    mycompany.engagement.product_orders
GROUP BY
    DATE_ADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', timestamp) / 1)*1, '20000101')
```

Returns:

```
Unrecognized name: MINUTE at [2:14]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select Product, 
  timestamp_trunc(Timestamp, minute) Timestamp,
  count(1) `Count`
from `mycompany.engagement.product_orders`
group by 1, 2
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(timestamp, MINUTE) as tm,
       COUNT(*)
FROM  mycompany.engagement.product_orders
GROUP BY tm;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I had to modify this query slightly (missing a comma): 

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(timestamp, MINUTE) as tm,
    COUNT(*)
FROM  mycompany.engagement.product_orders
GROUP BY tm;
```

But now how can I count the number of occurrences in each minute interval grouped by product?